# Why doesn't the container start?

Tags: node.js, docker

My docker-compose file is simple:

```
npm:
    image: node
    volumes:
        - C:\Users\Samir\npm\:/home/dev
    container_name: npm
```

When I run it:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I get:

```
Starting npm
```

Then, nothing happens:

```
docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Per default the Node image is designed for interactive use and simply [starts](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/baad247b9df8087d4c13a3a9bfb3c65833f424bb/5.10/wheezy/Dockerfile#L28) a Node REPL. When you run `docker-compose up -d` the Node REPL will start and exit immediately as no interactive terminal is availabe. Try:

```
docker-compose run -it npm
```

Note that this is currently not supported on Windows, you will need to use `docker run -it -v ... node`  instead.

If you want to start your application instead simply override the default [command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) in your `docker-compose.yml`